# Removing entire observation with a condition

Tags: r

I have made a survey and would like to remove all answers from people who answered ''no'' to being a parent?

The dataset is called ''tillid''

The variable is called ''Er du forældre'' and the answer is either ''Ja'' or ''Nej''

[An overview with table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXA47.png)

Comment: `can_sleep <- anwers[answer$parent == "no"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Question

In this case you have a data.frame that looks something like this:

```
> Tillid

  Id ... Er du forældre
1  1                 Ja
2  2                Nej
3  3  
4  4                Nej
5  5                 Ja
...
```

To create a minimal reproducible example use dput on a subset of rows and columns:

```
> dput(Tillid[1:5, c('Id', 'Er du forældre')])

structure(list(Id = 1:5, `Er du forældre` = c("Ja", "Nej", "",
"Nej", "Ja")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Next you want to show what you are trying to achieve (based on the minimal example):

```
> <insert code here>

  Id ... Er du forældre
1  1                 Ja
3  3  
5  5                 Ja
```

### Answer

In this case, the code to remove rows with the value 'Nej' is as follows (you might want to assign this to a new variable using `<-`)

```
> Tillid[Tillid$`Er du forældre` != 'Nej', ]

  Id Er du forældre
1  1             Ja
3  3
5  5             Ja
```

If you also want to exclude missing answers (of which you have 114), you could slice to only those rows with the value "Ja":

```
> Tillid[Tillid$`Er du forældre` == 'Ja', ]

  Id Er du forældre
1  1             Ja
5  5             Ja
```

As mentioned by [@mat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1612892/mat) in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71615711), it's good practice to avoid special characters, and spaces, in column names.

Answer (score 1):

```r
tillid <- tillid[tillid$`Er du forældre` != "Nej"]
```

The `!=` means "not equal to".

Alternatively:

```r
tillid <- tillid[tillid$`Er du forældre` == "Ja"]
```

Note that if you have missing values (`NA`), the first alternative will preserve them, whereas the second option will exclude everything that is not equal to `Ja`.

I would suggest to avoid special characters (e.g., æ) in your variable names as this can cause some bugs in R.